# Lua read text file to array

Tags: lua

How can I read a file like this:

```
11111
10001
10001
10001
11111
```

To a bidimensional array like this:

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

In Lua?

This is what I thought of:

```
for i = 1, number_of_lines do
  current_line = map_file:read("*line")
  character_array = {}
  for i = 1, #current_line do
    table.insert(character_array, current_line[i])
  end
end
```

However, I don't know how to get 'number_of_lines', this is, the number of lines in a text file with Lua. How can I do it?

Also, if there's some other easier way please tell me about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to get the number of lines. Just keep going until you run out of lines.

```
local line_data = {}
for line in map_file:lines() do
  local character_array = {}
  for i = 1, #line do
    character_array[#character_array + 1] = line[i];
  end
  line_data[#line_data + 1] = character_array
end
```